# Can't publish ASP.NET 5 with external library reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, dnx, kestrel-http-server, dnu

I have included an external reference of Moneris library eSELECTplus_dotNet_API.dll to my ASP.NET 5 RC1 project. It wrapped it alright and I can build project and run it using Kestrel. But when I publish it from VS or command line I got following error:

```
The package ID 'eSELECTplus_dotNet_API' contains invalid characters. Examples of valid package IDs include 'MyPackage' and 'MyPackage.Sample'.
```

I tried to rename library to a better name to fit nuget specs and it worked so I can publish it. But now when I run my project I got runtime error saying following:

```
      System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'eSELECTplus_dotNet_API, Version=2.5.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8cb9cd598f87e276' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Please advice.

Comment: Is the file name still "eSELECTplus_dotNet_API"? Or is your "better name" different? If you are still using the old name in other places when the new name is the actual name, this could explain your problem.

Comment: File name is still "eSELECTplus_dotNet_API.dll" but I called wrap project folder "eSelect.dotNet" because nuget uses folder name as package Id. So in my project dependencies I reference it as "eSelect.dotNet: 1.0.0-*"